# Raycasting giving erratic values

Tags: java, opengl, lwjgl

Using LWJGL3 and JOML.

I am trying to work out how to get the point on the terrain using a raycast system. I use the point to set a characters position to see what point is being outputted.

I don't think it is my terrain causing the issue since moving the character (with the keyboard or by just adding a value each frame) and attaching it to the terrain works fine.

The issues I get:

- Inverting the projection matrix causes the point to flicker between the correct position and some other point but I am not sure about the relationship with this other value.
- Not inverting the projection matrix stops the flickering but now the point moves away from the mouse position exponentially.
- Near the center of the screen the 2 positions will merge together.

If I print out the terrain point vector it comes out in scientific notation for some reason:

```
( 5.335E+1  3.849E-2 -9.564E+1)
( 8.804E+1 -6.256E-3 -2.815E+2)
( 5.335E+1  3.849E-2 -9.564E+1)
( 8.804E+1 -6.256E-3 -2.815E+2)
( 5.335E+1  3.849E-2 -9.564E+1)
```

If I print out each of the x, y and z values individually it is actually showing the correct position but is also flicking to another (the difference between which increases the further from the center of the screen that the mouse moves):

```
5.8912144, 0.016174316, -7.771721
6.1992702, 0.01574707, -11.79966
5.8912144, 0.016174316, -7.771721
6.1992702, 0.01574707, -11.79966
6.609352, 0.01815033, -8.793705
```

Raycasting class:

```
public class Raycast
{
    private static final int RECURSION_COUNT = 200;
    private static final float RAY_RANGE = 600;

    private Input input;
    private Vector3f currentRay = new Vector3f();

    private Matrix4f projectionMatrix;
    private Matrix4f viewMatrix;

    private Camera camera;
    private Terrain terrain;
    private Vector3f currentTerrainPoint;

    public Raycast(Camera camera, Matrix4f projectionMatrix, Terrain terrain, Input input) {
        this.camera = camera;
        this.projectionMatrix = projectionMatrix;
        this.input = input;
        this.viewMatrix = MathUtils.createViewMatrix(camera);
        this.terrain = terrain;
    }

    public void update()
    {
        viewMatrix = MathUtils.createViewMatrix(camera);
        currentRay = calculateRay();
        if (intersectionInRange(0, RAY_RANGE, currentRay)) {
            currentTerrainPoint = binarySearch(0, 0, RAY_RANGE, currentRay);
        } else {
            currentTerrainPoint = null;
        }
    }

    private Vector3f calculateRay()
    {
        float mouseX = (float) input.getMouseDx();
        float mouseY = (float) input.getMouseDy();
        Vector2f deviceCoords = getNormalizedDeviceCoordinates(mouseX, mouseY);
        //System.out.println(deviceCoords.x+", "+deviceCoords.y);
        Vector4f clipCoords = new Vector4f(deviceCoords.x, deviceCoords.y, -1f, 1f);
        Vector4f eyeCoords = toEyeCoords(clipCoords);
        Vector3f worldRay = toWorldCoords(eyeCoords);
        return worldRay;
    }

    private Vector3f toWorldCoords(Vector4f eyeCoords)
    {
        Matrix4f invertedView = viewMatrix.invert();
        Vector4f rayWorld = invertedView.transform(eyeCoords);
        Vector3f mouseRay = new Vector3f(rayWorld.x, rayWorld.y, rayWorld.z);
        mouseRay.normalize();
        return mouseRay;
    }

    private Vector4f toEyeCoords(Vector4f clipCoords)
    {
        Matrix4f invertedProjection = projectionMatrix.invert();
        Vector4f eyeCoords = invertedProjection.transform(clipCoords);

        return new Vector4f(eyeCoords.x, eyeCoords.y, -1f, 0f);
    }

    private Vector2f getNormalizedDeviceCoordinates(float mouseX, float mouseY)
    {
        float x = (2f * mouseX) / Constants.DISPLAY_WIDTH - 1f;
        float y = (2f * mouseY) / Constants.DISPLAY_HEIGHT - 1f;

        return new Vector2f(x, -y);
    }

    private Vector3f getPointOnRay(Vector3f ray, float distance) {
        //Vector3f camPos = new Vector3f(camera.getPosX(), camera.getPosY(), camera.getPosZ());
        Vector3f start = new Vector3f(camera.getPosX(), camera.getPosY(), camera.getPosZ());
        Vector3f scaledRay = new Vector3f(ray.x * distance, ray.y * distance, ray.z * distance);
        return start.add(scaledRay);
    }

    private Vector3f binarySearch(int count, float start, float finish, Vector3f ray) {
        float half = start + ((finish - start) / 2f);
        if (count >= RECURSION_COUNT) {
            Vector3f endPoint = getPointOnRay(ray, half);
            Terrain terrain = getTerrain(endPoint.x, endPoint.z);
            if (terrain != null) {
                return endPoint;
            } else {
                return null;
            }
        }
        if (intersectionInRange(start, half, ray)) {
            return binarySearch(count + 1, start, half, ray);
        } else {
            return binarySearch(count + 1, half, finish, ray);
        }
    }

    private boolean intersectionInRange(float start, float finish, Vector3f ray) {
        Vector3f startPoint = getPointOnRay(ray, start);
        Vector3f endPoint = getPointOnRay(ray, finish);
        if (!isUnderGround(startPoint) && isUnderGround(endPoint)) {
            return true;
        } else {
            return false;
        }
    }

    private boolean isUnderGround(Vector3f testPoint) {
        Terrain terrain = getTerrain(testPoint.x, testPoint.z);
        float height = 0;
        if (terrain != null) {
            height = terrain.getTerrainHeight(testPoint.x, testPoint.z);
        }
        if (testPoint.y < height) {
            return true;
        } else {
            return false;
        }
    }

    private Terrain getTerrain(float worldX, float worldZ) {
        return terrain;
    }

    public Vector3f getCurrentTerrainPoint() {
        return currentTerrainPoint;
    }

    public Vector3f getCurrentRay() {
        return currentRay;
    }
}
```

MathUtils class with view and projection matrices:

```
public class MathUtils {

    public static float baryCentric(Vector3f p1, Vector3f p2, Vector3f p3, Vector2f pos) {
        float det = (p2.z - p3.z) * (p1.x - p3.x) + (p3.x - p2.x) * (p1.z - p3.z);
        float l1 = ((p2.z - p3.z) * (pos.x - p3.x) + (p3.x - p2.x) * (pos.y - p3.z)) / det;
        float l2 = ((p3.z - p1.z) * (pos.x - p3.x) + (p1.x - p3.x) * (pos.y - p3.z)) / det;
        float l3 = 1.0f - l1 - l2;
        return l1 * p1.y + l2 * p2.y + l3 * p3.y;
    }

    public static Matrix4f createTransformationMatrix(Vector2f translation, Vector2f scale) {
        Matrix4f matrix = new Matrix4f();
        matrix.identity();
        matrix.translate(translation.x,translation.y,0f);
        matrix.scale(scale.x,scale.y,1f);
        return matrix;
    }

    public static Matrix4f createTransformationMatrix(Vector3f translation, float rx, float ry, float rz, float scale) {
        Matrix4f transformationMatrix = new Matrix4f();
        transformationMatrix.identity();
        transformationMatrix.translate(translation);
        transformationMatrix.rotate((float) Math.toRadians(rx), 1,0,0);
        transformationMatrix.rotate((float) Math.toRadians(ry), 0,1,0);
        transformationMatrix.rotate((float) Math.toRadians(rz), 0,0,1);
        transformationMatrix.scale(scale);
        return transformationMatrix;
    }

    public static Matrix4f createViewMatrix(Camera camera) {
        Matrix4f viewMatrix = new Matrix4f();
        viewMatrix.identity();
        viewMatrix = viewMatrix.rotate((float) Math.toRadians(camera.getPitch()), 1,0,0);//((float) Math.toRadians(camera.getPitch()), new Vector3f(1, 0, 0), viewMatrix);
        viewMatrix = viewMatrix.rotate((float) Math.toRadians(camera.getYaw()),0, 1, 0);
        Vector3f cameraPos = new Vector3f(camera.getPosX(), camera.getPosY(), camera.getPosZ());
        Vector3f negativeCameraPos = new Vector3f(-cameraPos.x, -cameraPos.y, -cameraPos.z);
        viewMatrix  = viewMatrix.translate(negativeCameraPos);
        return viewMatrix;
    }

    public static Matrix4f createProjectionMatrix() {
        Matrix4f projectionMatrix = new Matrix4f();
        float aspectRatio = (float) Constants.DISPLAY_WIDTH / (float) Constants.DISPLAY_HEIGHT;
        float fov = Constants.FOV;
        float near = Constants.NEAR_PLANE;
        float far = Constants.FAR_PLANE;
        projectionMatrix = projectionMatrix.perspective((float) java.lang.Math.toRadians(fov), aspectRatio, near, far);
        return projectionMatrix;
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A coordinate in view space is a [Cartesian coordinates](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cartesian_coordinate_system) with 3 components `x`, `y` and `z`. The projection matrix transforms from view space to clip space. Clip space coordinates are [Homogeneous coordinates](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Homogeneous_coordinates) with 4 components `x`, `y`, `z` and `w`.

Clip space coordinates can be transformed to normalized device coordinates by a  [Perspective divide](https://www.khronos.org/opengl/wiki/Vertex_Post-Processing#Perspective_divide).
This means the `x`, `y` and `z` component is divided by `w` component.

If you want to transform from normalized device space to view space, then you've to do the inverse operation. this means you've to transform by the inverse projection matrix and to divide the `x`, `y` and `z` component of the result by the `w` component of the result.

```java
private Vector4f toEyeCoords(Vector4f ndcCoords)
{
    Matrix4f invertedProjection = projectionMatrix.invert(new Matrix4f());
    Vector4f eyeCoords = invertedProjection.transform(clipCoords);

    return new Vector4f(eyeCoords.x/eyeCoords.w, eyeCoords.y/eyeCoords.w, eyeCoords.z/eyeCoords.w, 0.0f);
}
```